# Music player for Python not working

Tags: python, pygame

I want to be able to play multiple songs through a playlist using python, but it will only play the last song on the list. Please help.

```
from pygame import mixer # Load the required library
from os import listdir
k = listdir('C:/LOCAL')
print(k)
mixer.init()
for x in k:
    y = "C:/LOCAL/" + x
    print y
    mixer.music.queue(y)
    mixer.music.load(y)
    mixer.music.play()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you assume that playing music with pygame will pause the program until the music is finished - which is not the case. As a result, it tries starting a song, and then it's starting another, and another, etc.

There are a few ways of trying to correct this. You could either:

1. Use pygame events and "tell" pygame to fire an event when the song finishes (though this requires a display surface (window) to be opened within pygame), or
2. Detect the length of the song, and sleep for that amount of time (which is more compatible with your current code).

I'm going to assume that you would like to do option 2, since your code works better with it.

To get the length of an MP3 file (I've not tried it with any other types), you could use the [Mutagen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mutagen) library.

Some example code to get the length of an MP3 file (in seconds):

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
tracklength = MP3("/path/to/song.mp3").info.length
```

Then you could substitute the path with `y`, and `time.sleep` for the amount of time returned, before continuing to the next iteration of the loop.

Hope that helps.

(also, you don't need to queue a file before loading it - just `load` and `play`)

Comment: No problem, @user3570933 , though if my answer helped could you please accept it? It's the tick just below the arrows and number to the left of my answer.